# Tried loads of different suggestions, but Dash file search not giving results

Tags: unity, unity-dash, search, facebook, google-drive

After browsing many different questions and blog posts about Dash and trying updates and reinstalls of the lens packages the problem still persists: Dash will consistently display applications but no files at all.

Selecting 'files' in the 'Filter results' options does not produce any change (other than selecting some 'Source options' below such as 'Google Drive', 'Facebook' - all of which were not previously there, at least I don't remember ever seeing them!). It is deselected again as soon as I type additional characters into the search.

I would very much appreciate advice, and preferably to reset dash to a previous state where it worked fine - without suggesting searches in Facebook, Google Drive and what not. Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add which questions and blog posts did not help. What change did lead to your problems with Dash?

Comment: Thanks -- Perhaps the problem was a recent removal of Zeitgeist that I did since that process seemed to be getting stuck quite often. Anyway, I solved the issue now, after I noticed that 'Security & Privacy' was missing from system settings - after opening it from terminal the dash search suddenly worked again.